# Schemacrawler cannot retrieve table in SQL Server

Tags: schemacrawler

I cannot retrieve tables in SQL Server 2012.

Using the API, I cannot get any table.  If I set schema support to false, I get the table, but no columns:

```
        SchemaCrawlerOptions options = new SchemaCrawlerOptions();
        options.setSchemaInclusionRule(new RegularExpressionInclusionRule(databaseName));
        options.setRoutineInclusionRule(new ExcludeAll());
        //options.getDatabaseSpecificOverrideOptions().setSupportsSchemas(false);
        options.setTableInclusionRule(new RegularExpressionInclusionRule("(?i)|databaseName.\\W?+myTable\\W?+"));
        options.setSchemaInfoLevel(SchemaInfoLevel.standard());
        Catalog database = SchemaCrawlerUtility.getCatalog(connection, options);

        for (Table t : database.getTables()) {
            System.out.println("Table: " + t.getName());
            for (Column c : t.getColumns()) {
                System.out.println("Column: " + c.getName());
            }
        }
```

Using sc.cmd, I don't get any table at all:

```
sc -url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<server>:1433/<dbname> -user=<user> -password=<pwd> -c=brief -infolevel=standard -schemas=<dbname> -tables=.*\.<mytable>.* -outputformat=text


System Information
========================================================================
SchemaCrawler Information
-=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=-
product name                              SchemaCrawler
product version                           12.06.03

Database Information
-=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=-    
database product name                     Microsoft SQL Server
database product version                  11.00.3128
database user name                        <user>

JDBC Driver Information
-=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=-
driver name                               jTDS Type 4 JDBC Driver for MS SQL Server and Sybase
driver version                            1.3.1
driver class name                         net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
url                                       jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<server>:1433/<dbname>
is JDBC compliant                         false
```

I tried on MySQL, and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work by adding catalog name (i.e. "catalog_name.schema_name") to the schema name.

Answer (score 0):

Got it works with only the option : `options.setSchemaInfoLevel(SchemaInfoLevel.standard());`